# Global function to authenticate user sessions in Python's Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm looking to authenticate users every time a page is accessed in my application.

I wrote a session handling class for my web app. It's called like this:

```
s = Session(request.cookies.get('session_id'))

s.isValid()
>> True #The user is logged in

s.user_id
>> 21 #The ID of the user currently logged in.

u = User(s.user_id)
```

I'd like to include this logic into a global file that's called everytime a web page is accessed. This way from within my view handlers I can check if a user is logged in and access basic user information.

As an example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
@app.route('/profile')
def profile():

  if logged:
    render_template('edit-profile.html', 
                     first_name=u.first_name)
  else:
    render_template('profile.html')
```

Is this possible? Where would the code go (which file?) What would it look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do something like this...

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    try:
        g.user = User.query.filter_by(username=session['username']).first()
    except Exception:
        g.user = None
```

The login page would set the username field in the session. Then on each page load this code is executed. You can access g.user in all of your views and templates.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.before_request

Comment: Thanks. I have my views split up into multiple files. Could I put this code in views/__init__.py or something?

Comment: Yep. I put code like this in "hooks.py" - see my HelloFlask sample here: https://github.com/fogleman/HelloFlask

Comment: +1... my solution was going to be much, much uglier than that.

Comment: I'm a bit confused what code should go where, and how to call it. So in __init.py__ I put the @app.before_request decorator and function, then in my view file, within a function, what do I call? I took a look at your source on github but couldn't piece it together -- an example with multiple files would be really appreciated

Comment: In your view modules, just do `from flask import g` and you can access `g.user`

Comment: Ahh, didn't know g was a special global variable. Thanks!!

Comment: @FogleBird I noticed that the functions I put in before_request() get called for every access -- I suspect even for static content, which is pretty inefficient. Is there a way to restrict this just for one time per page load?

Comment: In a production environment you should not have Flask serving your static content.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look in [Flask-Login](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Login/). Maybe you will find something interesting there.